# SSRS Shared Data Cannot Connect for Some Reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to write SSRS reports. I have one solution with multiple reports in it, so I am using a shared data source.

[image: screen shot of shared data source]

For some reason, some of my reports are able to connect and **I can preview them**, but other reports cannot.

For the reports that are unable to connect, I get the error:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 94

[image: initialization string error]

I don't understand why the connection **works** for some reports (I can preview them), but not others since they are using the same shared data source and therefore should be using the same connection string.

I have no issue deploying the reports, even the ones that cannot connect. They all show up fine online.

How can I troubleshoot this error? Is there a way for me to see the exact connection string for each report if they are somehow using different strings?

**Edits:**

- I meant line 94, corrected above and below
- As requested by the comment, this is line 94 from the RDL file:
  [image: Line 94 from RDL file]

Comment: To be clear: you are only having this problem locally in Visual Studio?  For one of the reports with a problem, could you open the .rdl file with notepad and do ctrl-g (goto line) 96 and share what is on that line (plus 3-4 lines before & after).

Comment: @tgolisch yes this a problem locally in my Visual Studio 2017. Some reports preview perfectly, others do not  (all using the same shared data source). I added a screenshot of line 94 (I accidentally typed 96 in the question). It appears to be a field in the table.

Comment: Is line 94 the same Field Name for the reports that fail?  Are you using any report parts or sub-reports?  Does it call a stored proc or just ordinary SQL?